# 304 Error - Get /static/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js HTTP/1.1"

Tags: python, jquery, flask

[304 Error /static/js/JQuery Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1URNZ.png)

I have no idea why this errors suddenly occur because it works perfectly before this and suddenly when I try to run the program, it pops out these errors? How do I solve these problems?

Below are the codes of my jquery files:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add you log lines as text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP304 is not an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304). It is the server telling you the resource hasn't changed and you can use your cached version.

Only HTTP codes starting with 4 (it's not me, it's you) and 5 (it's not you, it's me) are errors.

Comment: ohhh i see, because i thought that was the one causing me to get an error 404.